# param filters in symphony cms

Tags: parameters, url-parameters, symphony-cms

I'm trying to get filtered xml from my fields section called "practice-info" on my home site (http://www.amarilaw.com/test/Home/). You can see in the image below how the Data Sources are set/. Also, my Home page has this data source selected as a page resource. What is the URL, then? I can't find any info on this seemingly obvious question. I assumed, for every title of the section practice-info, it would be /Home/theTitle, but I'm not seeing anything. I also thought /Home/?title=theTitle

I must be missing something here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added `title` to the `URL Parameters` field in your Symphony page?

[image]

The URL would be:

`http://www.amarilaw.com/test/Home/title-in-lowercase-url-form`

Answer (score 0):

And if your URL was `/Home/?title=theTitle` then the parameter would be `{$url-title}`. There's some more information available [here](http://symphony-cms.com/learn/concepts/view/url-parameters/).